# Access Context in PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-context, android-pageradapter

As you know, for inflating a view, we need context to get `LayoutInflater`.I have seen many tutorials that pass context as an argument to `PagerAdapter` to solve this problem. I recently have found that we can access context from `instantiateItem` like below:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Context context = container.getContext();
    ...
}
```

but I wonder whether it is best practice or not?

Comment: This is just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, totally fine. A `ViewGroup` is a `View` and `getContext()` will return you a `Context` to which the view is attached to, i.e. it's the outbound `Activity`. This is the context that you want to use for accessing layouts and resources while rendering adapter items.